# Spring AMQP - Unable to use ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter with RabbitTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

#### Context

A Springboot-based application needs to publish messages to rabbitmq in different format/content-type (xml & json). The application has a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp`, springboot version is 2.7.2.

The application has a global `RabbitTemplate` to communicate with the rabbitmq, and I'm trying to configure its `MessageConverter` to support multiple formats:  [ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter.html) seems to be the good option for that.

Configuration class looks like that (simplified version)

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                     final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter,
                                     final Jackson2XmlMessageConverter xmlMessageConverter) {
    final var rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter compositeConverter = new ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter();
    compositeConverter.addDelegate(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON, jsonMessageConverter);
    compositeConverter.addDelegate(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_XML, xmlMessageConverter);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(compositeConverter);
    return rabbitTemplate;
```

A custom service facade provides `sendMessage` feature to other services in the application, something like that:

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQService {
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(final String exchange, final String routingKey, final Object payload, String contentType, boolean persistent) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingKey, payload, message -> {
            message.getMessageProperties().setContentType(contentType);
            message.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(persistent ? MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT : MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
            return message;
        });
    }
}
```

#### Problem

I would like to use [RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#convertAndSend(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,org.springframework.amqp.core.MessagePostProcessor))  method to let Spring create the `Message` automatically, using the `MessageConverter`.

But these `convertAndSend` method will not pass the message properties to the `MessageConverter`: it will pass a temporary MessageProperties instance:

```
public void convertAndSend(String exchange, String routingKey, final Object message,
        final MessagePostProcessor messagePostProcessor,
        @Nullable CorrelationData correlationData) throws AmqpException {
    Message messageToSend = convertMessageIfNecessary(message);
    messageToSend = messagePostProcessor.postProcessMessage(messageToSend, correlationData,
            nullSafeExchange(exchange), nullSafeRoutingKey(routingKey));
    send(exchange, routingKey, messageToSend, correlationData);
}

protected Message convertMessageIfNecessary(final Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Message) {
        return (Message) object;
    }
    return getRequiredMessageConverter().toMessage(object, new MessageProperties());
}
```

The ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter will therefor always select the default converter as MessageProperties will always have the default ContentType set (octet-stream).

This makes `ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter` class a bit useless in this case. I don't find any `convertAndSend` method that take Message Properties as input and provide it to the converter.

Are there any other ways to make `ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter`  and `RabbitTemplate` work nicely together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a `ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter` was designed for the inbound messages conversion in the `MessageListenerContainer`. Where we have the whole `Message` context with respective properties and `contentType` in there.

On the publish side we indeed don't have an API to accept a `body` and content type to convert it to `byte[]`. Please, raise a GH issue and we will think what we can do to make it really as it is advertised in the docs even for message publishing.

Meanwhile, as a workaround, I'd suggest to call this converter manually before propagating result `Message` to the `RabbitTemplate.send()`.